# How to go over comma separted values in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My database structure is like this:

```
 Movie Name  GenreID**
 Movie1      1,2,3
 Movie2      2,4
 Movie3      4,5,16
```

I need to select a Movie name based on the Genre ID the user selected which I put inside the `genreIDArray[]`

Let's say for example the genreIDArray has values: `$genreIDArray = ['1','2','3'];`

My current query method is the ff:

---

Here I prepared each ID into parts so the result won't become `genreID LIKE (%1,2,3%)` because I checked this doesn't work.

So I did this separation loop:

`$queryParts  = array();
 foreach($genresIDArray as $genreID) {
     $queryParts[] = "'%".$genreID."%'";
 }`

After the separation loop I put together the final query:

`$genreString = implode(" OR genreID LIKE ",$queryParts);
$genreQuery = " SELECT * FROM movies WHERE (genreID LIKE {$genreString}) ";`

gave me this final query output:

`SELECT * FROM movies WHERE (genreID LIKE '%1%' OR genreID LIKE '%2%' OR genreID LIKE '%3%')`

This actually works, but apparently not that efficient because `genreID 11,12,13` and so on that start with `1` is also selected. I think I'm missing the MYSQL LIKE logic here. I've tried `'%$genreID'` which means to select the `starting` or `first` number/letter of a table data, but that's still the same thing, `$genreID%` doesn't and would not work because this only means genreid ENDING letters/number will be selected.

I hope I spelled that out clear enough. I'm in a bind here. Please help.
Thank you so much.

Comment: You should optimise your db design.. Create an attributes table and link each movie to a GenreID instead of having multiple values into one column.

Comment: its called normliseation: http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Comment: @Dagon Well, nearly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very cool function for that. You can use `FIND_IN_SET`.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1,colors)
```

But if its possible you should avoid such structures in your database and normalize your database.